# Revmob : I dont get revenue for installs - ios

Tags: ios, installation, revmob

I set up revmob in my game according to the SDK documentation. Everything seems to work right. However when I click on the ad and download the advertised game( and I launch it also). The install doesn't appear in my revenue, just the click. I tried to download it with my and my friend apple id also. I still see 0 installs and 10 click. How can I solve this problem, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the installs are not counted in real time. I suggest you to wait one or two days, and if nothing changes contact RevMob.

Comment: Its about 1 week when I tried first. Howevet still no installs :/. I allready contacted to them, but no ansere yet.